# Prevent generating inline CSS in Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I noticed that Datatables sometimes generates inline CSS (style='....'). Is there are way to remove them? Or at least make the code not add styles inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most accurate answer would be: yes, the code can be changed to stop adding *style=...* to the html BUT removing all of them would almost certainly break the datatable layout and its behavior.

Datatable plugin uses `style="..."` to set dynamic properties (like width, position) that (in most cases) cannot be determined before actually running the plugin. If they cannot be determined they cannot be styled beforehand using css classes so we end up in using `style="..."` for those.

Comment: I see. I read the documentation and I think that I can prevent those styles by setting some Settings on or off.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options in DataTables to turn off the `element.style` that generates with a table's generation.  I've found that setting `bAutoWidth : false` can sometimes turn off all of the inline styles, (even though it's just meant to turn off the inline width option), as well as initializing the table outside of `$(document).ready(function()`.

As for a single option to turn off all styles created by DataTables - I'm not sure there's a way to do that, but if someone else finds this old thread, try these two options and see if it fixes your problem!

Comment: I tested it , and really works ..Now in chrome element.style {} is empty